# How to make a delay for several candles, while the beginning of the entry was behind the red line. Standard delay cannot do this

Tags: pine-script, offset, tradingview-api

The usual delay methods don't have the effect I want. The delay I'm looking for should follow the red line of her level. But the usual delay just moves forward by one bar.[image]

Offset, Changing the timeframe didn't help either. The desired result in practice in the figure. As a result, the white line means where the green line should move exactly at the same level as shown in the figure.[image]

```
//@version=2 
study("MTF", overlay=true)
tim=input('5')
tim1=input('5')
out1 = security(tickerid, tim, open)
out2 = security(tickerid, tim1, out1)
plot(out1,color=red,linewidth = 4, transp = 0)
plot(out2,color=green, linewidth = 4, transp = 0)

//@version=5
indicator('MTF', overlay=true)
tim = input('5')
tim1 = input('5')
out1 = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, tim, open)
out2 = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, tim1, out1)
plot(out1, color=color.new(color.red, 0), linewidth=4)
plot(out2, color=color.new(color.green, 0), linewidth=4)
```

Comment: it is not reliable with MTF. First [convert your code to v5](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v5/migration_guides/index.html)

Comment: But that won't help. Using two types of barmerge.lookahead will also not give the desired result

Answer (score 0):

offset depends on the value selected in HTF
you can use a [switch](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-reference/v5/#op_switch)

Something like that:

```
//@version=5
indicator('MTF', overlay=true)
tim = input('5')
tim1 = input('5')
out1 = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, tim, open[1], lookahead = barmerge.lookahead_on)  //No repaint
out2 = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, tim1, out1)

htfOffset   = switch tim
    '5'     => -5
    '15'    => -15
    '30'    => -30
    '45'    => -45
    '60'    => -60

plot(out1, color=color.new(color.red, 0), linewidth=4, offset = htfOffset)
plot(out2, color=color.new(color.green, 0), linewidth=4)
```